# Allowing different users to sign up using same email address

Tags: authentication, liferay

Is there any way to allow new users to register for my site using the same (duplicate) email address?

For example, have user A and user B sign up using the same email address '***example@email.com***'. Since liferay assigns different id numbers to every user and users can only login to my site with their username, I don't think duplicate email addresses would cause any trouble.

This may not make a lot of sense, and I think it's pretty obvious why this is not allowed in liferay or any other cms in the first place, but business requirements are business requirements :(. So anyways I was wondering if it's possible to modify such behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you ask the business whose password to send should one user forget their password and provide their email address? What should happen if an email address changes that is shared between many accounts? Should all be updated or only one? When you're subscribed to the same forum categories, how many emails do you expect to get when someone writes a new topic...

Sometimes business requirements change when you ask more questions instead of just pushing back.

Comment: Yeah, I realize there are a lot of concerns to take care of when dealing with duplicate account information. Problem is we're migrating an application from joomla to liferay. Joomla was modified to allow this kind of behavior and we want to make user migration as seamless as possible, hence my question.

Comment: Yup, we managed to convince the project leader to abandon the whole email duplication idea. We're going for user association (groups) and communities instead. Thanks for the advice.